# C++ - For loop does not stop sometimes - Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am having a quite obscure problem while developing a function in C++. I am using multithreading on a splitted huge array to improve processing velocity.

My code:

```
    std::mutex mu;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    int N_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    std::vector<std::vector<KP>> queryKPs_split = splitVector(queryKPs, N_THREADS);
    std::cout << queryKPs_split.size() << std::endl;

    for (int thr = 0; thr < N_THREADS; thr++) {
        std::cout << thr << " " << N_THREADS << std::endl;

        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() {
            for (auto &kp : queryKPs_split.at(thr)) { ... }});
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes (not always) i get a out of range exception on the `queryKPs_split` at `queryKPs_split.at(thr)`. The reason is that the value of thr goes up to 8, while it should stop at 7 as described in the for loop (`N_THREADS = 8`). Does anyone has an idea of why this might be ocurring?

Here is the result of an unsuccessful run before the exception appears:

```
8
0 8
1 8
2 8
3 8
4 8
5 8
6 8
7 8
```

Thank you in advance!

David

Comment: You don't want to capture `thr` by reference.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for your commentary. Why don't I? It should not be of importance, am I wrong?

Comment: @molbdnilo Your advise did work. Could you please explain me why is this the case or redirect me to a place where I can get to understand it better? Thank you!

Comment: The the loop gives each thread a reference to `thr`, and then it _changes the value_ of `thr`. If you think that is "not of importance", then you might want to spend some more time learning the basics of the language (esp., the meaning of "reference") before you dive in to the deep end with threads.

Comment: @jameslarge that is exactly my point. The thr is not being changed inside the lambda. It is exclusively used to address a thr-th element in the array. So, it should not matter, does it?

Comment: `thr` is changed outside the lambda, that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your commentaries and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're capturing `thr` by reference, so as the `for` loop increases the variable your thread will see the changes to it. Capture it by value instead:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread([&, thr]() {
            for (auto &kp : queryKPs_split.at(thr)) { ... }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing `thr` by reference.

This means that all the threads reference the same `int`, and when you use `thr` inside the lambda you don't get the value that `thr` had when the thread was created, but its current value.

If a thread accesses that value after the last increment but before the loop has ended, its value will be `N_THREADS` and `at` throws an exception.

If a thread accesses it after the loop has ended, the behaviour is undefined.

The moral of this story is that `[&]` is convenient to write but easily leads to surprising behaviours.
It's usually best to capture as explicitly as possible;

```
std::thread([thr, &queryKPs_split]() {
```